# Returning first letter of NSString capitalized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uisearchbar

I would like to return the first letter of an `NSString` capitalized. I have an `UISearchDisplayController` that displays section titles according to the title of the search results.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle;
    if (searching) 
        sectionTitle = [searchSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    else
        sectionTitle = [[collation sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];

    return sectionTitle;

}
```

And to return the letter, in my search function,

```
[searchSectionTitles addObject:[lastName firstLetter]];
```

How can I make

```
- (NSString *)firstLetter
```

return the first letter of an `NSString`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

the code below will capitalize the first letter of a string, in this case the string to capitalize the first letter of is called sectionTitle

```
NSString *firstLetter = [[sectionTitle substringToIndex:1];

firstLetter = [firstLetter uppercaseString];
```

Answer (score 2):

use `[yourString substringToIndex:1]` to get first letter